# Python code to find the binary representation of a number and check if both are palindromic, doesn't return True

Tags: python-3.x

The task is: The decimal number, 585 = 1001001001 (binary), is palindromic in both bases. Write a program that reads a number and checks if its palindromic in both bases.

```
n = int(input())

#Creates a binary representation of n
m = n
reversed = 0
reversed1 = 0
binary = 0 
while n != 0:
    mod = n % 2
    n //= 2
    binary = 10 * binary + mod


print(binary)
#Finds out if the num is  palindromic

while m!=0:
    c = m % 10
    reversed = 10 * reversed
    reversed = reversed + c

    m = m // 10

print(reversed)
#Finds out if the binary is palindromic
i = binary
while i!=0:
    c = i % 10
    reversed1 = 10 * reversed1
    reversed1 = reversed1 + c

    i = i // 10

print(reversed1)
#If both the num and binary are palindromic, it should print True

if reversed1 == binary and reversed == n:
    print('True')
else: 
    print('False')
```

It works for `reversed1 == binary`, however it doesn't work for `reversed == n`. Both should be `True`,also for better code readability, I've tried to write both palindromic cases in one `while loop` and do `reversed, reversed1 = 0, 0` but it didn't seem to work. It worked only with separate `loops`.
So my question is why it does not `print True` and could I have wrote both palindromic cases in one `while loop?`

Comment: Which number do you enter and what is the output of `print(reversed1, binary, reversed, n)`?

Comment: I enter `585` and the output is  `1001001001 1001001001 585 0`.. which is also wrong because n is not `0` it is `585`

Comment: I found the fix i just needed to do `f=n` and `print(f)` instead. Thank you!